# How to bulk edit wav files?

Tags: audio, sox, wav

I need to cut off the first say 3 seconds from a batch of wav files.
Is there a way to do it from the command line or using a linux native program?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sox` (see `man sox` for its options) to process one file:

```
sox music.wav shortermusic.wav trim 3
```

The timing value is *hours:minutes:seconds*, defaulting to the smallest interval(s) if parts are omitted, so here we can use `3` for three seconds. Negative values are measured from the end of the file.

After that it's just a case of using a loop to iterate across the set of files

```
mkdir trimmed
for m in *.wav
do
    printf 'Trimming: %s\n' "$m"
    sox "$m" trimmed/"$m" trim 3
done
```

The trimmed files will be put into a subdirectory `trimmed` so that you don't get to trim them twice, accidentally

If you have `ffmpeg` installed you can visually check the duration of a file:

```
ffprobe music.wav 2>&1 | grep Duration
```

or a little [more elegantly](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/FFprobeTips#Formatcontainerduration) in seconds:

```
ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 music.wav
```