# How to fade out batch wav files?

Tags: sox

I need to apply a fade out of 2 seconds on a batch of wav files (with names including spaces like C 0 120-127.wav).

The files length varies, but I need a fade out of 2 seconds from the end of each file, regardless of the file length.

I know this can be done with sox, but the tutorials I checked include other actions (fade in or convert) or are for single files where you specify input and putput, and this is confusing (I'm a sox newbie).

I need the files names to remain the same, although piping the output to another folder is also acceptable.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi! You got quite a nice answer to your last question (last **two** questions, actually), from which it should be nearly trivial to solve the "batch" aspect of this question, and you said you found tutorials that only differ from what you need by additional things: so obviously, you should explain what you found and why you can't remove these additional operations yourself! Our role here is not to do every single incantation of sox for you, but to enable you to solve such problems yourself. The way your question is currently stated, you're trying to use us as free code writing service!

Comment: As I specified, I'm very new at sox. I couldn't figure out how the fade in and out parameters work, since both seem to come into play. You could have probably gave a workable solution faster than writing a patronizing comment.

Comment: I couldn't. I would have to look up the same articles you've read - but forgo to link to our better even to write a synopsis of. We **need** you to describe what you're not understanding, and obviously it's not fair to expect that you can ask anything that takes an expert short time to research: do your own research and become the expert, within reason. So, that's why I wrote that quick comment: to let you know what you can do to help us help you. If that's not how you intend too deal with that, your choice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are four different parts to your question

1. Loops are as in answers ([(1)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/754544/100397), [(2)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/756904/100397)) to your previous questions:

   ```
   for wav in *.wav
   do
       echo "Processing: $wav"
       sox "$wav" "processed_$wav" ...
   done
   ```
2. Filenames with spaces should be quoted. So `"this file.txt"` or `'my music.wav'`. If you are using a variable, it should be in double quotes, e.g. `"$wavfile"`.
3. Fading from the end. You can use `man sox` on your own machine to read up the documentation on the `sox` command. Or a similar manual page is available [online](https://man.archlinux.org/man/sox.1.en). Search through four or five matches for "`fade`" and determine the syntax for fading part of a sound file. Remember that time points can be zero or positive to start from the beginning of the sound file and negative to work backwards from its end.
4. You cannot overwrite a file while reading/processing it. Instead you have to write to a different file, and then if the writing was successfully completed, replace the original file with the modified one. Personally if I'm doing this I always save the original as a backup (just in case something went wrong with the processing and I need to restore it). Here's a typical but simplified method for doing this:

   ```
   if sox music.wav 'new music.wav'        # Write to "new music.wav"
   then
       # Successful, so replace original with new version
       mv -f music.wav music.wav.bak &&    # Save original - optional
       mv -f 'new music.wav' music.wav     # Rename new as original
       rm -f 'new music.wav'               # Try to remove new version in case mv failed
   fi
   ```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain, but you might be overestimating my expertise :) I read sox man page several times, but couln't figure out how to implement fade out alone. For example, on a single test file $sox infile.wav outfile.wav fade 0 0 2  (supposedly fade in start value fade in end value fade out start value) split the file in 3 different fades. I tried a few more combinations and just gave up and used audacity.

Comment: @black-clover so you found the [section on `fade`](https://man.archlinux.org/man/sox.1.en#fade)?

Comment: Your example would have created a fade for the last 2 seconds of the sound file (I've just tested with `play music.wav fade 0 0 2`)

Comment: Are you sure you didn't have an unquoted filename that contains spaces in its name? If that was the case please read my answer, point #2

Comment: Yes, I eventually figured that out, for future use. Your answer will hopefully also help other users.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't figure out how to do it in sox but found a way with audacity.

I created a macro with the following commands:
select all
studio fade out
export wav (this would seem redundant but it didn't work otherwise)

Then I used the apply macro > palette > files function and selected all the samples in the directory.

NOTE: first you need to create a macro output directory and set that default in edit > preferences > directories

The process took longer than it would probably have taken with sox but it worked.